# How to disable button if user isn't logged in?

Tags: php, yii2

Current code (doesn't work)

```
    <?php echo Html::submitButton('', ['name' => 'action',
'value' => 'minus', !Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? 'disabled' => 'disabled' : ''])
```

How to disable button if user is guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a falsy value like `null` in conjunction with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), which by default will remove any falsy items from an array (if you don't provide a callback):

```
<?php 
    echo Html::submitButton('',array_filter([
        'name' => 'action',
        'value' => 'minus', 
        'disabled' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? "disabled" : null
    ])); 
?>
```

### Edit

As stated by "Sam" in the comments, the Yii framework will automatically omit the attribute if the value is `false` - or assign the attribute key as the value (i.e. `disabled="disabled"`) if it's `true`. [Take a look in the source to see how this works](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1891-L1895). This ultimately results in a much cleaner piece of code:

```
<?php 
    echo Html::submitButton('', [
        'name' => 'action',
        'value' => 'minus', 
        'disabled' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
    ]); 
?>
```

Comment: This answer while not wrong is not the optimal way.

Comment: @Sam great find. I didn't know the framework, but I've added it to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php 
    $attribs = (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?  ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'minus', 'disabled' => 'disabled'] :  ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'minus']); 
    echo  Html::submitButton('',$attribs); 
?>
```

Comment: In all cases it makes disabled button. In one — with attribute 'disabled', in second — disabled="disabled"

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
<?php echo Html::submitButton('', ['name' => 'action',
'value' => 'minus']  + (Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? ['disabled' => 'disabled'] : []))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 has built in support for boolean attributes: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1890

So you should just do:

```
Html::submitButton('', ['name' => 'action', 'disabled' => !\Yii::$app->user->isGuest]);
```